# Activating Applescript via Notifications

Tags: macos, applescript, apple-push-notifications, osx-mavericks

Is it possible for Applescript to detect incoming notifications, and read the contents of the notifications? I know that we can use Applescript to send notifications, but I haven't been able to find anything about doing Applescript detaching notifications. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything applescript can do is given in the dictionaries of the various applications on your computer. So you must look in the dictionaries. As such if I go to the File menu in Script Editor and choose "Open Dictionary" I can find "Notifications Scripting" in the resulting list. That sounds like it might help! So open that and see if there's something in there that will help you.

I looked and I can see "notification delivered" in the dictionary which sounds like it will do what you want. I'm not familiar with it so you'll have to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks! You're right - I didn't have Notifications Scripting installed hence it wasn't in my dictionary. But thanks for pointing me towards it, have downloaded it and it does look like exactly what I'll need :) Much appreciated.